# Listing, Code, Beispiel oder Quelltext?

Tags: word-choice, technical-terminology, scientific-language

Welches der folgenden Wörter ist am besten für Quelltextbeispiele in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten (z.B. Masterarbeit) der Informatik zu verwenden?

- **Listing**: Sehe ich in vielen Büchern, ist für mich aber kein Deutsch. Der Duden führt Listing nur im Wertpapierkontext auf.
- **Code(beispiel)**: Wird auch oft benutzt, aber "fühlt" sich ebenfalls nicht deutsch an.
- **Quelltext**: Fühlt sich am deutschesten an, aber wirkt etwas "verkrampft".
- **Beispiel**: Habe ich auch gesehen. Hier beschränkt man sich auf die  Bedeutung als Beispiel unabhängig davon was es eigentlich ist.

## Veranschaulichung

Es geht um die rot unterstrichene Stelle:

[image]

Es handelt sich meistens um Beispielcode, also einzelne Methoden oder kleine Klassen oder auch mal nur Teile einer Klasse. Manchmal aber auch um JSON oder XML. Ich bin nicht sicher ob letztere gleich behandelt werden sollten.

Comment: Eventuell sollte hervorgehoben werden, dass ein allgemeiner Begriff für Einschübe, die Quelltext enthalten, gesucht wird. Im konkreten Fall des in der Frage gezeigten Screenshots könnte ich mir nämlich ansonsten "Algorithmus" gut vorstellen - das passt aber (ebenso wie "Beispiel") nicht für alle "Listings".

Comment: "Fühlt" sich _Beispielcode_ für Dich deutscher an als _Codebeispiel_?

Comment: Wie wäre es mit Programm?

Comment: Ich persönlich kann nicht nachempfinden, wieso Quelltext von verschiedenen Leuten als verkrampft empfunden wird... ich kenne das als ein ganz normales und gebräuchliches Wort aus persönlichen Gesprächen mit Programmierern.

Comment: Du solltest in deiner Frage erläutern, in welchem Fachgebiet / Wissenschaftsbereich du dich bewegst. Dein Beispiel lässt vermuten, dass es irgendwie um Computerprogramme geht. Aber du solltest das einmal explizit klarmachen, denn Fachgebiet und Kontext haben dann wieder Einfluss auf die Wortwahl.  Bisher sprichst du nur ganz allgemein von "wissenschaftlichem Arbeiten". Das ist zu (!) allgemein.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann habe ich hinzugefügt. Interessanterweise habe ich selber jetzt "Beispielcode" verwendet. Das "kam ganz natürlich aus mir heraus".

Comment: @problemofficer  Danke. Jetzt finde ich die Frage schneller verständlich.

Comment: @Lykanion: Ich persönlich spreche selten Deutsch mit anderen Programmierern, aber soweit ich weiß benutzen deutsche Programmierer sowohl "Code" als "Quelltext". Das variiert von Person zu Person. Ich würde wohl selbst "Code" sagen, finde aber "Quelltext" absolut nicht verkrampft.

Comment: Das kommt darauf an, worauf sich der Textblock-Titel beziehen soll! Das ist eine grundlegende Entscheidung bei der Dokument-Struktur: entweder bezieht sich der Titel auf den Strukturtyp des Dokuments (also z. B. einfach "Textblock" bzw. "Abbildung" bei Bildern - oder halt "Listing"), oder aber der Titel soll sich auf den Inhaltstyp beziehen. Dann wäre eher "[Source] Code", "Quelltext", "Beispiel", "Auszug" angebracht. Kommt auch darauf an, ob es im gleichen Dokument noch Textblöcke eines anderen Typs gibt (z. B. SQL).

Answer (score 7):

**Quelltext** ist korrekt (**Quellcode** würde auch gehen).

*Code* würde man noch akzeptieren, hängt aber vom Kontext ab.

Listing wird niemand mit "Source code" assoziieren. (edit: Scheint ein antiker Begriff zu sein der mir (Baujahr 1982) nicht geläufig ist. Ältere Semester würde es scheinbar verstehen)

PS: Ich bin Software-Entwickler.

Comment: Ich würde Quellcode nehmen

Comment: Ich bin auch Programmierer und sage, dass *Listing* im Kontext eines Buchs über Programmiersprachen und deren Einsatzgebiete vollkommen normal ist. Quellcode oder -text ist aber in Ordnung.

Comment: Und wahrscheinlich bist Du zu jung, um mit Listing einen Quelltext zu assoziieren.

Comment: So ist es. Listing war früher der übliche Begriff für Quelltext. Meiner Ansicht nach wird der aber nur noch selten verwendet. Heute ist Quelltext oder Quellcode üblich.

Comment: 'Listing wird niemand mit "Source code" assoziieren.' - zumindest in der Zeitschrift [IX](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IX_%E2%80%93_Magazin_f%C3%BCr_professionelle_Informationstechnik) wird *Listing* auch in aktuellen Ausgaben routinemäßig für die Beschriftung von Quelltextauszügen verwendet.

Comment: *"Listing"* ist im Englischen immer noch der richtige Begriff für ausgedruckten *Source Code*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listing_(computer) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmausdruck

Comment: @PiedPiper Mag sein, aber es geht ja um das deutsche Wort. Und bis zu dieser Frage habe ich "Listing" noch nie als Übersetzung gelesen.

Comment: @HelmutMustermann Wenn nur deutsche Wörter gesucht werden, fällt natürlich auch *"Code"* weg (und auch *"Quellcode"*)

Comment: Auf [dieser Seite](https://pixelnostalgie.de/2015/04/run-for-retro-vom-c64-basic-befehl-zur-run-zeitschrift/) (ganz unten) findet sich ein Bild einer deutschen Computerzeitschrift aus den 80-ern, das den Begriff groß in der Überschrift zeigt. Ein [anderes Beispiel](https://www.c64-wiki.de/wiki/Listing) zeigt nur einen Ausschnitt, aber auch dort wird der Begriff verwendet. Wie @besc in seiner Antowrt schreibt: ein Generationenproblem.

Comment: @PiedPiper: Code ist längst ein deutsches Wort. Es wurde von 25 Jahren eingebürgert. Neben dem Da-Vinci-Code und ähnlichen - es vergeht kaum ein Tag, ohne dass auf Phönix irgendein dämlicher Code im Titel einer Pseudodoku vorkommt. Sprachforscher reden seit langem von restricted vs. elaborated Code. Jede Würstchenbude hat heute einen Code of Conduct. Die Codes der Modeindustrie sind in aller Munde. Alles ist hübsch kodifiziert.

Comment: @CarstenS: Wer ist zu jung, und wie stellt man das fest? Du weißt schon, dass man gezielt Diskussionsteilnehmer adressieren kann, in dem man einen Klammeraffen dem Usernamen voranstellt?

Comment: @userunknown per Default der, auf dessen Beitrag ich antworte.

Comment: Mein Default ist immer der Beitrag direkt über meinem.

Comment: In den 1980er Jahren wurden Quelltexte noch gedruckt in Zeitschriften abgebildet (listing: ausgedruckter Quelltext). Der Benutzer hat das dann (hoffentlich fehlerfrei) abgetippt. Da war das Wort "Listing" noch üblich. Heute wird sowas nicht mehr ausgedruckt, also auch keine Listings mehr.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: "Heute wird sowas nicht mehr ausgedruckt" - was ist dann mit den heutzutage in jeder Zeitschriftenhandlung erhältlichen gedruckten Zeitschriften, die Quelltextbeispiele in vielen Artikeln erhalten?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Die drucken selten noch vollständige "Listings" aus, soweit ich weiß. Die benutzen nur noch kurze Teile des Quelltexts, die als Verdeutlichung des Besprochenen gebraucht werden (und so mache ich das auch, in meinen Artikeln, genauso wie die meisten anderen). Die vollständigen Quellen können dann aus dem Internet geholt werden. Es gibt also keine richtigen Listings mehr, die mühsam vom Benutzer begetippt werden müssen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: z.B. wie in den meisten Artikeln auf CodeProject oder ähnlichen Sites. Da werden nur sog. "snippets" eingefügt, keine vollständigen Listings. Das wird in Zeitschriften nicht anders gemacht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: /begetippt/abgetippt/.

Comment: @CarstenS: in der Zeit, in der du schreibst, könnte jemand schon ein Kommentar eingefügt haben, und dann ist dein "Default" hin. Es macht in Kommentaren wie diesem *immer* Sinn, die Person, zu der man schreibt, zu benennen. Das macht das Ganze viel übersichtlicher, da man hier keine richtigen "Threads" hat.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Beitrag ≠ Kommentar. Zum Beispiel wird, so weit ich weiß, der Autor der Antwort über alle Kommentare informiert.  Du jetzt aber nur wegen des Klammeraffen.

Comment: @Carsten: Trotzdem ist es gut, immer eine Attribution eizufügen. Da gibt es keine "Defaults" und es kann Kommentare dazwischen geben..

Answer (score 7):

Ich arbeite in der Softwareentwicklung, und meinem Eindruck nach ist **Listing** ein heutzutage (2018) gängiges Wort für den gesuchten Einsatzzweck. Es wird beispielsweise in aktuellen Ausgaben von in Deutschland verbreiteten deutschsprachigen Computerzeitschriften wie [c't](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%E2%80%99t) und [iX](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IX_%E2%80%93_Magazin_f%C3%BCr_professionelle_Informationstechnik) verwendet.<sup>1</sup> Siehe dazu auch die [Autorenhinweise des Verlags](https://www.heise.de/developer/Hinweise-fuer-Autoren-1218380.html), die ebenfalls von "Listings" sprechen.

Um konkret auf die in der Frage erwähnten deutschsprachigen wissenschaftliche Arbeiten einzugehen, ist festzustellen, dass der Begriff *Listing* auch sowohl in wissenschaftlichen Publikationen (z.B. [hier](https://dl.gi.de/bitstream/handle/20.500.12116/2397/51.pdf), [hier](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter_Fruehwirt/publication/264974983_InnoDB_Datenbank_Forensik_Rekonstruktion_von_Abfragen_uber_Datenbank-interne_Logfiles/links/53f8f5210cf27925e2e0e274/InnoDB-Datenbank-Forensik-Rekonstruktion-von-Abfragen-ueber-Datenbank-interne-Logfiles.pdf) und [hier](https://dl.gi.de/bitstream/handle/20.500.12116/1302/paper48.pdf)) aus dem aktuellen Jahrzehnt als auch in aktuellen Bachelor- und Masterarbeiten aus der Informatik (z.B. [hier](http://dbis.eprints.uni-ulm.de/1342/), [hier](http://eprints.dbis.informatik.uni-rostock.de/128/1/MarcEricMeier_Bachelorarbeit.pdf) und [hier](https://wr.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/_media/teaching/sommersemester_2016/pir-16-tobias_klinke-presentation.pdf)) auftritt.

**Quelltext** könnte eventuell auch passen, legt den Fokus aber meines Erachtens eigentlich woandershin. Gefühlsmäßig wirkt "Quelltext 5: ..." als Beschriftung für einen Quelltextauszug in einem Artikel ähnlich deplaziert wie "Deutsch 5: ..." as Beschriftung für ein natürlichsprachliches Zitat (in deutscher Sprache). **Quelltextauszug**, **Quelltextabschnitt** oder **Quelltextausschnitt** passt schon erheblich besser, ist aber natürlich auch länger. Bis auf die Länge gilt dasselbe für **Code**.

Wörter wie **Beispiel** oder **Algorithmus** können für sich genommen oder zusammengesetzt mit Quelltext oder Code verwendet werden, eignen sich aber nur in bestimmten Fällen (wenn das Gezeigte tatsächlich ein Beispiel für irgendetwas ist bzw. wenn tatsächlich der Algorithmus im Vordergrund steht, und nicht z.B. die Syntax einer Programmiersprache).

---

<sup>1</sup>: Wie von anderen Benutzern angemerkt, könnte der Begriff mit einem Generationenproblem im Zusammenhang stehen. Ich wurde ungefähr Mitte der 80er Jahre geboren und bin damit offenbar zu jung, um mit *Listing* irgendetwas "Veraltetes" zu assoziieren.

Comment: Dass man das hier und dort schon mal sieht will nicht sagen, dass es richtig ist. Ich finde *Listing* für ein Codebeispiel ziemlich übertrieben. Ein Listing ist der vollständige Abdruck eines ganzen Quelltexts.

Comment: Ich habe mal bei meinen ehemaligen Kommilitonen nachgefragt. Keinem U40er sagt "Listing" etwas.

Comment: @HelmutMustermann: Interessant. Wenn einem dieser ehemaligen Kommilitonen nun also das Wort "Listing" in einer der genannten Zeitschriften oder einem Paper begegnet, wie nehmen sie das dann auf? Verstehen sie ernsthaft den Text nicht, oder ist der Begriff im Kontext eventuell plötzlich doch klar?

Answer (score 3):

Software-Entwickler hier, der in den 90ern mit der Computerei angefangen hat.

Dass sich keine der Alternativen richtig gut anfühlt, mag daran liegen, dass gerade in der IT das Englische so übermächtig ist, dass es einfach keinen allgemein üblichen und vertrauten deutschen Begriff gibt. Ich z.B. habe nur ein einziges deutsches IT-Fachbuch im Schrank stehen (erschienen 1995, verwendet »Listing«).

Allgemein für einen »Schnipsel Code« gefällt mir **Quellcode** am besten. Es ist als Wort relativ kurz, bringt die Sache ohne zusätzliche Bedeutungsnuancen auf den Punkt und fühlt sich sehr vertraut an. Ich hatte an »Quelltext« herumüberlegt. Ja, das ersetzt das englisch angehauchte *Code* mit einem deutschen Wort. Aber am Ende stimme ich zu: Es wirkt – imo *weil* es eingedeutscht ist – etwas verkrampft.

**Listing** kenne ich als Begriff für einen »Codeschnipsel«, ist aber stark mit der Vergangenheit assoziiert. 80er Jahre mindestens. Vergilbtes beige und grün-schwarze, kastenförmige Minimonitore. :) Das kann natürlich ein Generationenproblem sein.

**Codebeispiel** fühlt sich auch sehr rund an, aber nur dann, wenn der Schnipsel wirklich ein Beispiel ist. Angenommen, das Ergebnis eines wissenschaftlichen Artikels ist die effiziente Implementierung eines bestimmten Algorithmus. Wenn dann am Quellcode »Beispiel« dransteht, wäre das schon etwas seltsam.

Und wenn wir schon dabei sind: **Implementierung** kann im richtigen Kontext auch gut passen – wenn z.B. erst die Theorie behandelt und dann eine beispielhafte (ha!) Umsetzung in Code gezeigt wird.

Comment: *Schnipsel Code* == *code snippet*? Und Code muss nicht nur Implementierung(en) enthalten, sie enthält auch Deklarationen, usw.  *Implementierung* klingt daher für mich (Programmierer seit 1980) absolut falsch. Die Implementierung ist nur ein Teilbereich.

Comment: @RudiVelthuis Implementierung meine ich normalerweise in der Bedeutung »der Quellcode zu einer abstraken Idee« oder »Prozess der Umsetzung einer abstraken Idee in Quellcode«. In meiner Welt (v.a. C++, Python) wird das Wort so gut wie nie anders benutzt. In deiner Bedeutung scheint mir das eher eher von der Programmierplattform abzuhängen. In C++ z.B. wäre das Pendant zur Deklaration die Definition, und »implementation« ist der Normalbegriff für die Umsetzung des C++-Standards in einem Compiler/einer Standardlib.

Comment: Rudy, nicht Rudi. Egal was du normalerweise *meinst*, Implementierung als allgemeine Bezeichnung für Quellcode/Quelltext, also als Übersetzung von "source code", macht keinen Sinn.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Rudy, sorry. Das meine nicht nur ich. Das ist die nahezu ausschließliche Verwendung, die ich tagtäglich höre und lese; in deutsch und englisch gleichermaßen. Für sehr viele Leute scheint das sehr viel Sinn zu machen. Was stört dich daran?

Comment: Wirklich? Ich nicht, und ich programmiere auch tagtäglich.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Offenbar bist du in einer außergewöhnlichen Nische unterwegs. Du musst nur “implementation of” oder “implementierung von” angooglen, dann springt dich meine gewohnte Bedeutung förmlich an.

Comment: "Implementierung" als Synonym für "Quellcode" ist einfach falsch, Punkt. Nicht alle Quellcodes sind Implementierungen. Dass der Begriff also in Google gefunden wird, auch im Zusammenhang mit Programmiersprachen, hat keine Bedeutung. Und meine Nische ist gar nocht so klein, würde ich sagen.

Answer (score 2):

In Ergänzung der anderen kompetenten Antworten hier:

Für mich wäre "Quelltext" oder "Quellcode" zunächst der typische Begriff für den HMTL-(etc.)-Code, der mir auf dem Browserbildschirm eine Website anzeigt und den ich mir auf gesonderten Wunsch ("show source code") auch in seiner HTML-(plus-x)-Originalform anschauen kann. Da dieser Code jedoch heute oft erst beim Aufrufen der Seite im Server speziell für diesen Betrachtungsfall erzeugt wird, ist dieser Quellcode nicht identisch mit dem Code, der wiederum im Server sitzt und die ganze Sache steuert.

Dies nur vorab.

Für den Fall in der Ausgangsfrage frage ich mich, ob nicht auch

> Programmcode

ein gut brauchbares Wort wäre.

Vorteil: Auch dem zufällig vorbeikommenden Leser, der also nicht von vornherein weiß, dass es hier um eine Arbeit aus der Informatik geht, wird damit eigentlich auf Anhieb klar, was gemeint ist. Wenn es nur nur "Code" oder "Quelltext" heißt, könnte auch in einer literaturwissenschaftlichen oder sprachwissenschaftlichen Arbeit vorkommen.

Comment: Für den Normalmenschen gebe ich dir recht mit dem Programmcode. Aber die Frage zielt auf die akademische Welt, und dort ist das Wort potenziell mehrdeutig. Wenn du deinen Quelltext durch den Compiler jagst und hinten ein ausführbares Programm rausfällt, ist das auch Programmcode – halt nicht menschenlesbar, sondern maschinenlesbar und auf der CPU (oder einem virtuellen CPU-Ersatz) direkt ausführbar. Die meisten Leser würden »Programmcode« vermutlich trotzdem intuitiv als Quellcode verstehen, aber in einem Paper würde ich mich darauf im Zweifel nicht verlassen wollen.

Comment: @besc. Zuerst, nicht alle Compiler generieren direkt Maschinencode, und wenn doch, dann heißt das auch Maschinencode oder schlicht Programm, aber nicht Programmcode. Programmcode ist schon der Begriff für Quellcode. Der Nachteil dieses Begriffes ist allerdings, dass Quellcode nicht immer Programmcode ist. Es kann auch der Code einer Bibliothek (DLL, .lib, .sa, usw.) oder einer einzelnen Quelldatei (oder Teile daraus) sein, oder eben nicht real existierender Quellcode, der nur verdeutlicht wie man etwa benutzt (sieht man z.B. oft auf S.O.), usw.

Answer (score 1):

> Quelltextauszug

oder

> Quellcodeauszug

hört sich für mich am "wissenschaftlichsten" an und wäre das, was ich in einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit nehmen würde. Da das Abgedruckte ja normalerweise nict der ganze Quelltext ist, ist "Auszug" auch am präzisesten.

Comment: +1. Das ist in meinen Augen bisher der beste Vorschlag.

Comment: Wieso "Auszug"? Ein Beispiel kann ja ein vollständiger Quelltext sein. Aus meiner Erfahrung würde ich sogar sagen, dass das oft genug der Fall ist (auf Stack Overflow heißt sowas MCVE). Die Bezeichnung *Quelltextbeispiel* aus der Frage ist m.E. schon richtig, da gibt es nichts zu verbessern.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Wenn du z.B. Quelltextauszüge aus einem real existierenden größeren Programm zeigst (wie das bei einer akademischen Arbeit üblich und notwendig ist) ist *Beispiel* sicher falsch, weil das nicht wiedergibt, dass es sich sozusagen um ein wörtliches Zitat handelt.

Comment: @tofro: Dann nennt man es Quelltexauszug (oder Quellcodeauszug). Aber das ist nicht immer der Fall, also ist diese Bezeichnung nicht immer richtig.